# CheckBox Not Sending Checked Value to Access Database C# Asp

Tags: c#, ms-access

This is my C# code and my issue as the title says is my checkbox values are not going into my access database, or at least not changing them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
        Label1.Text = (string)Session["sesionicontrol"];
    }

    protected void txtPass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void check1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Declare Variables
        string username = txtEmailLogin.Text;
        string password = txtPasswordLogin.Text;
        username = username.Trim().ToLower();
        password = password.Trim().ToLower();

        //Handle null or empty fields
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)))
        {
            lblError.Text = "Please Enter a vaild Username or Password";
        }
        else if (((username.Contains("@mu.edu") || (username.Contains("@marquette.edu")))))
        {
            //Run select query and populate a table, then check to see if the user and pass are in that table
            OleDbConnection conn = null;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                string connString =
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                string query = "Select Count(*) From Team Member Where Email = ? AND Pass = ?";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // handle error here
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            //checking if there is a result in the virtual table, if there is they successfully logged in
            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Welcome!";
                /// Take to Homepage
                CommonClass.txtEmail = txtEmailLogin.Text;
                Server.Transfer("HomePage.aspx", true);
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Incorrect Username or Password";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        DataTable gridTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

            string query = "INSERT INTO [Team Member] (FirstName, LastName, Email, Pass, Age, Hobbies, FavoriteColor, Major) VALUES('" + txtFirst.Text + "','" + txtLast.Text + "', '" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtPass.Text + "','" + txtAge.Text + "','" + txtHobbies.Text + "', '" + txtFavorite.Text + "','" + txtMajor.Text + "')";
            string query1 = "INSERT INTO [Team Member] (Soccer, Basketball, Football, Softball) VALUES('" + c1.Checked.ToString() + "',  '" + c2.Checked.ToString() + "',  '" + c3.Checked.ToString() + "',  '" + c4.Checked.ToString() + "')";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            lblError1.Text = ("Registered Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError1.Text = ("Error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void btnReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFirst.Visible = !txtFirst.Visible;
        txtLast.Visible = !txtLast.Visible;
        txtEmail.Visible = !txtEmail.Visible;
        txtPass.Visible = !txtPass.Visible;
        txtPassConfirm.Visible = !txtPassConfirm.Visible;
        btnRegister.Visible = !btnRegister.Visible;
        btnReg.Visible = !btnReg.Visible;

        c1.Visible = !c1.Visible;
        c2.Visible = !c2.Visible;
        c3.Visible = !c3.Visible;
        c4.Visible = !c4.Visible;

        txtAge.Visible = !txtAge.Visible;
        txtHobbies.Visible = !txtHobbies.Visible;
        txtFavorite.Visible = !txtFavorite.Visible;
        txtMajor.Visible = !txtMajor.Visible;

        lbl1.Text = "Sports you want to play";
        lbl2.Text = "Age";
        lbl3.Text = "Hobbies";
        lbl4.Text = "Favorite Color";
        lbl5.Text = "Major";
    }

    protected void c2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void c1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

My database looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are appending to Access Yes/No fields then I would try removing the single quotes (') from the second INSERT INTO line:

```
string query1 = "INSERT INTO [Team Member]
(Soccer, Basketball, Football,     Softball)
VALUES(" + c1.Checked.ToString() + ",  " 
+ c2.Checked.ToString() + ",  " 
+ c3.Checked.ToString() + ",  " 
+ c4.Checked.ToString() + ")";
```

Comment: This was the answer, thanks man. I was wondering if you might be able to answer one more question. I wanted to run a series of if statements that would check to see if the checkbox was checked and if it was put the user into the corresponding database(soccer, basketball, football, softball). This would all be done when the registration button is clicked. It would have to support being added to multiple databases at once. Would I do multiple queries for each if?

Comment: Not sure how that worked considering that query1 is never executed. Not to mention 2 insert statements should result in 2 rows, which is not what you would want I would think

Comment: Okay so I am trying something new instead of the if statements. I am going to add the new questions so I can post my code, maybe you can take a look and provide some advice. Thanks

Comment: @JSON http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897420/how-to-add-data-from-one-access-datatable-into-another-datatable-in-the-same-dat

Answer (score 0):

First, The reason your check box values never get inserted is because your OleDbCommand is defined like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
```

Using query as the command.text.  query1 is never referenced to this and thus never executes.

Second (more important), you need to have the insert statement as one statement, not 2.  Calling 2 Insert statements would cause 2 rows to added to the table. One containing values from query, and one containing the checkbox value from query1. You should define your query in one string like this

```
    string query = "INSERT INTO [Team Member] " +
        "(FirstName, LastName, Email, Pass, Age, Hobbies, FavoriteColor, Major, Soccer, Basketball, Football, Softball) " +
        "VALUES('" + txtFirst.Text + "','" + txtLast.Text + "', '" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtPass.Text + "','" + 
        txtAge.Text + "','" + txtHobbies.Text + "', '" + txtFavorite.Text + "','" + txtMajor.Text  + "','" +
        c1.Checked.ToString() + "',  '" + c2.Checked.ToString() + "',  '" + c3.Checked.ToString() + "',  '" + c4.Checked.ToString() + "')";
```

Comment: I will make the changes and report back. Thanks