# How to add Data from one Access DataTable into Another Datatable in the same DataBase Where the data inserted relies on a textbox control?

Tags: c#, ms-access

So I am trying to add members of a 'Team Member' datatable into a 'SoccerBlue' DT which represents a team. I have set up a textbox so the user will basically be able to view a gridview of players, choose a player, then write the email of the player which detirmines which player from 'Team Member' to add to 'SoccerBlue'. The issue I am coming up with is the values are not being added to the 'SoccerBlue' DT on button click.

There error I get is Error occurred: No value given for one or more required parameters.

the db

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHfFE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WWah.png)

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = null;
    DataTable gridTable = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

        string query = "INSERT INTO [SoccerBlue] " + "(FirstName, LastName, Email, Age) " + "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, Age " + "FROM [Team Member] " + "WHERE Email = txtAdd.Text";
        // string query = "INSERT INTO [Team Member] (Soccer, Basketball, Football, Softball) VALUES(" + c1.Checked.ToString() + ",  " + c2.Checked.ToString() + ",  " + c3.Checked.ToString() + ",  " + c4.Checked.ToString() + ")";


        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        lblError.Text = ("Teamate Added!");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = ("Error occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't added it to the datatable...

Comment: I know that is my issue, what am I messing up?

Comment: You most likely have a required column in your [SoccerBlue] table that is not being inserted here.  Meaning, one of the columns in your DB is defined to be NOT NULL without an auto generated default value assigned to it.  The problem is not that a row cannot be inserted without defining this value.  It would be one that you do not have in your list of columns names to insert.

Comment: I think I am not doing a great job of explaining the Textbox. What I am trying to make it do is someone will view the players in the gridview, someone then will type the email of the play they want to add. The textbox will then be compared to the [Team Member] if it matches with a email in the datatable then the values of FirstName, LastName, Email, and Age will be added to [SoccerBlue].
Also the new error I am getting now is Error occurred: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Email = Thomas.Scott@mu.edu'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming txtAdd.Text is a Textbox then this line:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [SoccerBlue] " + "(FirstName, LastName, Email, Age) " + "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, Age " + "FROM [Team Member] " + "WHERE Email = txtAdd.Text";
```

Should be this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [SoccerBlue] " + "(FirstName, LastName, Email, Age) " + "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, Age " + "FROM [Team Member] " + "WHERE Email = '" + txtAdd.Text + "'";
```

Comment: the txtAdd.Text is what I am checking the data base against. I am adding a picture now of what it all looks like. I am stil getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: This is my new error Error occurred: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Email = Thomas.Scott@mu.edu'. Where Thomas.Scott@mu.edu is the text in the textbox being compared to the dt [Team Member]

Comment: Yeah the syntax was definitely wrong in the first example.  Now it is seeing the email address.  I'll update my answer for the new error.